# Squarespace complex product variations- workaround

Tags: javascript, html, css, cart, squarespace

I've been creating a website through squarespace and the product I'm selling is a made-to-order product with 9 different options to choose from and within those 9 options are 6 different sub options.

To add each product variant to squarespace seems unreasonable and there has to be a better way around this. I've made the code for setting up my own product customization page but I need help making the checkout button on my page link up with squarespace's checkout page. (listing each product dosage) Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

```css
a{
  font-size:25px;
}

html {
  background-color: #333;
}
body {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

select {
  outline: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 100%;
  background: #2c343c;
  color: #747a80;
  border: #2c343c;
  padding: 5px 3px 5px 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

select option {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #010;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div1>
    <a>Caffeine</a>
    <select id="caffeine" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="0.02">150</option>
      <option value="0.04">200</option>
      <option value="0.06">250</option>
      <option value="0.08">300</option>
      <option value="0.1">350</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a> Beta-Alanine</a>
    <select id="ba" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
      <option value="0.00">0</option>
      <option value="0.02">1000</option>
      <option value="0.04">1500</option>
      <option value="0.06">2000</option>
      <option value="0.08">2500</option>
      <option value="0.1">3000</option>
  </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a>Creatine HCL</a>
    <select id="Creatine" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
      <option value="0.00">0</option>
      <option value="0.02">1000</option>
      <option value="0.04">1250</option>
      <option value="0.06">1500</option>
      <option value="0.08">1750</option>
      <option value="0.1">2000</option>
  </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a>BCAA's 2:1:1</a>
    <select id="BCAA" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
      <option value="0.00">0</option>
      <option value="0.02">2000</option>
      <option value="0.04">4000</option>
      <option value="0.06">6000</option>
      <option value="0.08">8000</option>
      <option value="0.15">10000</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a>Citrulline Malate</a>
    <select id="CM" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
      <option value="0.00">0</option>
      <option value="0.02">1000</option>
      <option value="0.04">2000</option>
      <option value="0.06">3500</option>
      <option value="0.08">6000</option>
      <option value="0.18">8000</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a>Taurine</a>
    <select id="Taurine" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
      <option value="0.00">0</option>
      <option value="0.02">250</option>
      <option value="0.04">500</option>
      <option value="0.06">750</option>
      <option value="0.08">1000</option>
      <option value="0.05">1250</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a>Betaine</a>
    <select id="Betaine" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
      <option value="0.00">0</option>
      <option value="0.02">500</option>
      <option value="0.04">1000</option>
      <option value="0.06">1500</option>
      <option value="0.08">2000</option>
      <option value="0.05">2500</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a>Arginine</a>
    <select id="Arginine" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
      <option value="0.00">0</option>
      <option value="0.02">500</option>
      <option value="0.04">750</option>
      <option value="0.06">1000</option>
      <option value="0.08">1250</option>
      <option value="0.05">1500</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a>Tyrosine</a>
    <select id="Tyrosine" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
      <option value="0.00">0</option>
      <option value="0.02">500</option>
      <option value="0.04">750</option>
      <option value="0.06">1000</option>
      <option value="0.08">1250</option>
      <option value="0.05">1500</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
  </div1>
  <a>Price per Serving: </a>
  <div id="pps">0</div>
  <br>
  <a>Price per Container (30 Servings): </a>
  <div id="priceresults">20</div>
  <br>
  <a>Mg Total: </a>
  <div id="mgresults">0</div>

  <button>Add to cart</button>
</body>

</html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function myFunction(val) {
    var price1 = $(caffeine).val();
    var price2 = $(ba).val();
    var price3 = $(Creatine).val();
    var price4 = $(BCAA).val();
    var price5 = $(CM).val();
    var price6 = $(Taurine).val();
    var price7 = $(Betaine).val();
    var price8 = $(Arginine).val();
    var price9 = $(Tyrosine).val();
    var mg1 = document.getElementById('caffeine').options[document.getElementById('caffeine').selectedIndex].text;
    var mg2 = document.getElementById('ba').options[document.getElementById('ba').selectedIndex].text;
    var mg3 = document.getElementById('Creatine').options[document.getElementById('Creatine').selectedIndex].text;
    var mg4 = document.getElementById('BCAA').options[document.getElementById('BCAA').selectedIndex].text;
    var mg5 = document.getElementById('CM').options[document.getElementById('CM').selectedIndex].text;
    var mg6 = document.getElementById('Taurine').options[document.getElementById('Taurine').selectedIndex].text;
    var mg7 = document.getElementById('Betaine').options[document.getElementById('Betaine').selectedIndex].text;
    var mg8 = document.getElementById('Arginine').options[document.getElementById('Arginine').selectedIndex].text;
    var mg9 = document.getElementById('Tyrosine').options[document.getElementById('Tyrosine').selectedIndex].text;

    var totalprice = Number(price1) + Number(price2) + Number(price3) + Number(price4) + Number(price5) + Number(price6) + Number(price7) + Number(price8) + Number(price9);
    var totalmg = Number(mg1) + Number(mg2) + Number(mg3) + Number(mg4) + Number(mg5) + Number(mg6) + Number(mg7) + Number(mg8) + Number(mg9);
    
    var numb1 = (totalprice*30+20)/30;
    var x = numb1.toFixed(2);
     
    var numb2 = totalprice*30+20;
    var y = numb2.toFixed(2);
    
    $("#pps").html(x);  
    $("#priceresults").html(y);
    $("#mgresults").html(totalmg);
  }
</script>
```

rough example: http://codepen.io/garvdaddy/pen/JKQbxa